# find when matrix is not diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A = \begin{pmatrix}
3&0&0\\
0&a&a-2\\
0&-2&0
 \end{pmatrix}$
A is not diagonalizable

find $a$.

how can I tell when $a$ is diagonalizable by it's characteristic polynomial>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: A non-diagonalizable matrix must have a repeated eigenvalue.

Comment: But that is not a sufficient condition.

Comment: @Bernard Yes, it is necessary but not sufficient.  However, this allows you to identify the candidates for $a$, which can then be checked in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Hints.

First, compute that characteristic polynomial $p$ of $A$.

Then observe that $p$ has a double root $\lambda=2$ iff $a=2$.

Comment: No, that's $a=4$.  Also  $\lambda=3$ can be a double root.